# No option to switch window managers with 16.04 laptop

Tags: gnome

I  have been using Ubuntu for years, am familiar with installing the various window managers via both synaptic and command line using apt-get. I recently upgraded both my computers, a desktop and laptop to 16.04.

All is well with the desktop. The installed window managers all show up at/alongside the login screen. With the laptop no such luck. Regardless which window manager I install, or reinstall at the login screen all I get is the list of logins including Guest, no option to select from the list.

Is there a manual way via command line to select a window manager? And of course, how do you fix the problem?